# Serve Files From Naked Root Domain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I run Google Ads on my Google-App-Engine-hosted website (www.bigriddles.com), and they tell me I need to have an "ads.txt" file served from the root domain (i.e. http://bigriddles.com/ads.txt, as opposed to http://www.bigriddles.com/ads.txt).

My DNS is hosted on Gandi, and I created their "ALIAS" record (which I think just does CNAME flattening or something similar) to alias "bigriddles.com" to "ghs.googlehosted.com."  I chose "ghs.googlehosted.com" because that's what I CNAMEd "www.bigriddles.com" to (many years back), and that CNAME has been working fine.

However, now when I visit "bigriddles.com", I get an "HTTP 301 Moved" to "www.bigriddles.com", and as far as I can tell, this response isn't coming from any code I wrote (I've looked through my code and don't see anything that would redirect this).  Furthermore, there is a "Server: ghs" header in the response from "bigriddles.com", whereas if I visit "www.bigriddles.com", which works fine, the response includes the header "Server: Google Frontend".  I'm not sure if there is some hint of my problem in the difference between those two Server headers.

Anyway, I'm not sure exactly what's going wrong.  It could be a DNS issue.  I say this because "dig www.bigriddles.com" comes back with the IP 172.217.14.115, whereas "dig bigriddles.com" comes back with "172.217.168.211", so maybe one of these really is a "ghs" server and the other is a "Google Frontend" server (I'm not sure the difference) and this "ALIAS" DNS solution just isn't going to work.

More likely though I feel like maybe there is just some settings problem with my App itself where it's not set up to allow the apex domain "bigriddles.com", and if I change that setting it will start working?

I have gone through the steps on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains.  When I view the "Custom Domains" for my project, I see "www.bigriddles.com" and "m.bigriddles.com", but I don't see the naked domain "bigriddles.com".  However, when I try to add it on that page, it tells me that "bigriddles.com" is already mapped to a project, so I'm not sure what to make of that.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hi @jstoff, After reading Waelmas answer and your comments therein I'm afraid that your situation would require to open a ticket with Google Cloud Support to provide you with a definite answer. If your old domain mapping is indeed the cause of your issue this would need to be confirmed and addressed on Google's end. I kindly suggest you to reach out the support team.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It looks like I can only file a support ticket if I pay $150/month for the upgraded support package, so I guess I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an issue with your domain provider.

You can use [this tool](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/) that might help you contact the domain provider with detailed info.

If they insist it's not an issue on their side (I strongly believe it is), then you should contact Google Cloud Platform Support so a deeper inspection can be made on your project.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Could you explain why you think it's an issue with the domain provider?  Given that the A record being served for the naked domain does seem to be a Google server, it feels like that part is working correctly.

Comment: The reason I believe it's an issue with your domain provider is because the naked domain seems to be getting a random ip every time which is usually an issue with the domain mapping. To be even more sure follow this link and make sure your configuration is correctly set for the naked domain https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/mapping-custom-domains

Comment: I have the same problem and I don't believe the problem is DNS. I simply set up A records for the naked domain as same as the `www` subdomain, then when you access the naked domain path information are all dropped. Google app engine has an issue about this, we need to find a workaround.

Comment: The mapping for the domain mentioned in the question is not set up correctly. I've checked it multiple times and it gets random IPs every time. Please follow this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/mapping-custom-domains#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application and make sure you are following the on screen settings for the naked domain. The settings are not exactly the same for the naked domain and the subdomains so pay attention to that part.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Apologies if I'm doing something silly but I'm not able to get through those Add-Domain steps.  I'll comment with the steps I'm doing and what's blocking me:

Comment: 1. I click "Add a Custom Domain".
2. It asks "Select the domain you want to use".  I choose "bigriddles.com" from the dropdown and click "Continue"
3. The next step is "Point your domain to bigriddles-hrd".  But it seems to want a non-naked domain.  The filler example text in the text box is "subdomain.bigriddles.com".  If I enter "bigriddles.com" into this text field, it gives me the message "bigriddles.com is already mapped to a project" and won't let me continue.

I checked all of my other App Engine projects just in case I had mapped "bigriddles.com" to one of them, but none had it.

Comment: One theory is that "bigriddles.com" is associated with the non-"High-Replication-Datastore" version of my app (called just regular "bigriddles", which I turned off years ago when setting up HRD).  Is it possible that I associated "bigriddles.com" with that project back then, and it's still associated somehow?  The "domains" page for the regular "bigriddles" project (https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains?project=bigriddles) has nothing on it (it just shows me a "Welcome to App Engine" message and a button to "Create Application").

Answer (score 0):

If you're also using G Suites for your domain, the criminal is G Suites' `Domain -> Redirect`. If it is, it's a pity that Google does not let us turn off the so-called feature.

Since G Suites use as the same entry point as App Engine, you have no chance to solve this other than moving your site outside Google services or stop using G Suite.